# Pointer and struct array manipulation in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

```
 #define MAX_KEYS 65

struct Key {

        int id;
        char cryptkeys[MAX_KEYS];
};



int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
int MAX_LINE = 69;
struct Key *table[3];
struct Key *(*p)[] = &table;
//allocating space for the pointers in array
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        table[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Key));
}
//parsing the id and the keys
char id[3];
char key[65];  

for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        struct Key *k = (struct Key*)malloc(sizeof(struct Key));
        string = a[i];
        strncpy(id, string, 3);
        id[3] = '\0';
        k->id = atoi(id);
        for(int j = 4; j < strlen(string); j++) {
                key[j-4] = string[j];
        }
        strcpy(k->cryptkeys, key);
        table[i] = k; 
        printf("%s", table[i]->cryptkeys); //this will print
}
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(table) -1; i++) {
        printf("%d", table[i]->id); //seg fault here, what is the difference from above?
        printf(" ");
        printf("%s", table[i]->cryptkeys);

}
return 0;
}
```

Hi everyone, I had a question about manipulating pointers in C. I have declared an array of pointers that will be filled with structs that I have created. Each struct accepts a int and string value that I read in from a file. My question is about editing the values inside of my array, specifically assigning new values and accessing the values already in there. I assign my values after parsing them from the file, but I get a segmentation fault when I try to print them out below. Why does my code keep segfault in my last loop, do I have to print out values in an array of pointers differently than I normally would? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(table)` is not 3. It's actually 24 which is 3*8 (number of array elements*size of an address). You get segmentation fault because you try to access `table[3]` (and so on) which is not allocated.

Comment: I need to add size of an address is 8 assuming a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, so if I actually want to malloc three slots in an array I need to do the command malloc(24)?

Comment: `Key *table[3];` in your code implies an array with 3 elements each of them having the size of `Key*`. In 64-bit machines and environments, an address (no matter what it's referring to) is 8 bytes long (in 32-bit machines it's 4 bytes). What you did is equivalent of `Key* table = (Key*)malloc(3*sizeof(Key));` or as you said `Key* table = (Key*)malloc(24);`, although the last form is not recommended since it degrades the readability of your code.